# Change sort order for a System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive

Tags: c#, uwp, c#-ziparchive

For some reason ZipArchive sorts by date modified. I need it to sort by name. I tried sorting it as one would sort any other collection of objects yet it makes no difference, it still sorts by date modified.

```cs
// I tried this
var orderedArchive = archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

// and this
foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.OrderBy(x=>x.Name))
...
```

The results are like I did no sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was:

```
var orderedEntries = 
                from entry in archive.Entries
                orderby entry.Name
                select entry;
```

Comment: Hi Nexus, nice to see you answered, can it make your code work as expected? If yes, please mark it as an answer, which will help more people.